# How to change Mate panel background type from bash?

Tags: mate, panel, ubuntu-mate

I want to change Mate panel's background type from a bash script. So far, tried to set it to color with:

`gsettings set org.mate.panel.toplevel.background 'color'`

but that doesn't seem to work. How should I do it?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my 16.04 LTS I can set background to *color* using

```
dconf write /org/mate/panel/toplevels/bottom/background/type "'color'"
```

But please note that you need to have correct values of *opacity* and *color*. For example the code below will set green background with full opacity:

```
dconf write /org/mate/panel/toplevels/bottom/background/color "'#00ff00'"
dconf write /org/mate/panel/toplevels/bottom/background/opacity 65535
```

To disable *color* use

```
dconf write /org/mate/panel/toplevels/bottom/background/type "'none'"
```

---

Note: got this solution while monitoring the situation with `dconf watch /` on the terminal.