# Where can I lookup the current color of the top and bottom panel in Ubuntu Mate?

Tags: themes, mate

I am making an app that runs in the system tray, and I would like to be able to swap out the icon whenever the top panel bar changes color, so I can put up a black   icon when the panel is white and a white icon when the panel is black.

To do this, I need to figure out where Ubuntu Mate stores the current color of that panel. I've found ways to accomplish this in Windows and OSX, as well as regular Ubuntu and Kubuntu, but when I run `sudo find / -mmin 1` after changing the theme, the only thing that appears to change that's relevant is `~/.config/dconf/user` but I wasn't able to find a color using `dconf Editor`, or even the name of the theme I have changed to. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Mate panel background type from bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177477/how-to-change-mate-panel-background-type-from-bash)

Comment: The helps with the scenario where the user has explicitly set the panel color to something other than the theme color, but the default config for the Mate panel it to use the color from the system theme. I didn't know about `dconf watch /` though; that was definitely helpful, so thanks for that. I found the CSS in the GTK theme that controls this though, so I will be posting my own answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default configuration, the panel in Ubuntu Mate 19.10 uses the system theme to determine the panel color, which is defined by one of the GTK3 themes stored in one of the two theme folders: `/usr/share/themes` and `~/.themes`.

- Use `dconf read /org/mate/marco/general/theme` to get the currently configured theme.
- Use `dconf watch /org/mate/marco/general/theme` to monitor it for changes.

Both just give the name though, so you'll need to look in both folders for a theme with the matching name.

Once you have the theme name, you can parse the CSS files in `<theme folder>/<theme name>/gtk-3.0` for the current `background-color` value for `.mate-panel-menu-bar`, which appears to be what defines the panel color in GTK3 themes on Mate. The specific css file that `.mate-panel-menu-bar` is defined in is not consistent, and the color itself may be a hex value, an RGB value, part of a GTK function call, or a CSS alias like `@dark_bg_color` for a color defined in one of the other CSS files, so you may need to parse multiple files to see the whole picture.

When the user changes the default, and manually sets the panel color by setting the Background tab in panel properties from `None (use system theme)` to `Solid color`, you can see the following with `dconf read`:

- `/org/mate/panel/toplevels/top/background/type` will change from `none` to `color`
- `/org/mate/panel/toplevels/top/background/color` will get a color defined in the format `rgb(#,#,#)`

  - (eg. `rgb(0,0,0)` for black or `rgb(255,255,255)` for white)

The `/top/` part of the path above may also change depending on which panel the user has set the color for. In my case, I needed the indicator applet which is where tray-like icons live, so I have to use `dconf read /org/mate/panel/objects/indicatorappletcomplete/toplevel-id` (which defaults to `top`) to see which panel I am looking at the colors for.